# pybind11 and blitz array

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a C++ module that I use with pybind11 to expose functionality in python.
It all works nice, for example I am exposing classes, functions and enumerations from the C++ code, for example:

```
    py::class_<MapErrorMsg>(m, "MapErrorMsg")
        .def(py::init())
        .def("SetFilename", &MapErrorMsg::SetFilename)
        .def("GetFilename", &MapErrorMsg::GetFilename)
        .def("SetWarnLevel", &MapErrorMsg::SetWarnLevel)
        .def("Warn", (void (MapErrorMsg::*)(MapErrorState, std::string, std::string)) &MapErrorMsg::Warn, "Warn with a level and two string messages")
        .def("Warn", (void (MapErrorMsg::*)(MapErrorState, std::string, int)) &MapErrorMsg::Warn, "Warn with a level, a string message and an integer message")
        .def("WarnAddInfo", (void (MapErrorMsg::*)(MapErrorState a_level, std::string, std::string)) &MapErrorMsg::WarnAddInfo, "Desc ToDo")
        .def("WarnAddInfo", (void (MapErrorMsg::*)(MapErrorState a_level, std::string, double)) &MapErrorMsg::WarnAddInfo, "Desc ToDo")
        .def("__repr__", [](MapErrorMsg& a) { return "<almass_py.MapErrorMsg mapped to file '"+ a.m_warnfile + "' >";} );
```

```
    m.def("CreateErrorMsg", CreateErrorMsg, "Instantiate the g_msg MapErrorMsg object");
```

```
      py::enum_<MapErrorState>(m, "MapErrorState")
        .value("WARN_BUG", WARN_BUG)
        .value("WARN_FATAL", WARN_FATAL)
        .value("WARN_UNDEF", WARN_UNDEF)
        .value("WARN_FILE", WARN_FILE)
        .value("WARN_MSG", WARN_MSG)
        .value("WARN_TRIVIAL", WARN_TRIVIAL)
        .value("WARN_ALL", WARN_ALL)
        .export_values();
```

However, I now need to expose a function that returns a  blitz::Array<int,2> , and this is not recognized by pybind11, it would be nice if it was recognized as a numpy array for example.

Do I need to write a custom type caster, and how would this be integrated ?
https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/cast/custom.html